# Atualizar automaticamente dados obtidos de api json - Volley

Tags: android, json, volley

Olá galera estou com o seguinte problema tenho uma aplicação que usa volley pra obter determinado dado json através de api até ai tudo bem ela funciona corretamente mas o problema é o cache do volley que não reseta até a aplicação ser fechada completamente, exemplo enquanto o cel não for desligado ou a propria aplicação ser fechada pelo gerenciador de tarefas os dados da json não vão atualizar de que maneira posso fazer para que em exemplo a cada 30 minutos seja atualizado os dados obtidos.

Meu Code:

```
JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(JsonURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            String valor = obj.getString("valor");
                            String data = obj.getString("data");

                            results.setText("Vale R$: " + valor );
                            datav.setText("Última atualização: " + data);

                        }  catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}},
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        results.setText("Erro ao obter dados");
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(arrayreq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode usar a biblioteca do [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
 e setar a cada X tempo efetuar a requisição novamente.

Porém a implementação deste Alarme para chamar uma função você deverá criar um [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=pt-br). É meio complexo a implementação, mas existem bons conteúdos ai na própria API Android.

Tive algo parecido porém era executado também quando o App deveria estar finalizado. Espero ter ajudado

Ou senão no modo mais bruto, você cria uma thread executando a cada tempo X dentro de um loop infinito.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o AlarmManager para executar a cada x minutos como já dito, ou utilizar o framework da google [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html), onde você também seta de quanto em quanto tempo irá executar o código.